# How can I find an appropriate replacement air filter for my furnace?

Tags: furnace, air-filter

**Background**: I got a Bryant 915SA furnace with my new house and it's time to replace the air filter.

**Problems**:

1. The filter is not branded so I don't know what company made it.
2. The filter is not a standard size; it's approx. 24.5" x 15.5" x 3.75"
3. I haven't found a data source indicating who made it.
4. I suspect the furnace installer (who's happy to sell them) is overcharging for replacements.
5. The furnace manual lacks details on recommended air filter suppliers.

**Suspicions**: I *suspect* the air filter is by GlasFloss based on comparing the Amazon picture to my actual filter (image attached)

**Question**:
How can I determine which brands and models are appropriate replacements for this air filter?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a replacement for your filter?

Answer (score 5):

It's a standard 25" x 16" x 4" filter (41625 is the size as well as the part number for that filter).

You can pick them up at any DIY store in the US for about $40.

Comment: That's inaccurate. I tried a "standard" filter and it didn't fit the opening.

Comment: So order one from Bobs Heating, using that part number. It'll still arrive looking very much like a 4x16x25 filter. https://www.bobsheating.com/product/single-replacement-filters/. He's selling at $38.50, which is pretty much street price.

Comment: How is that street price? Comparable prices are a 2-pack or 3-pack for $40. Only challenge is I don't know Bob's specific provider.

Comment: Big box prices are $32 each, maybe 2 for $40. Buy from a HVAC company, $40 each won't be out of the ballpark; they don't have the economy of scale. You'll never find Bobs supplier; they're screen-printed with his logo, so he's buying white-label. All you can do is go to a store with a tape measure, or call Bobs and ask them what size to buy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had any luck getting information from the web site listed on the filter? I've read that filters are never the size they are marked, that it's rounding for general public consumption. According to this: http://www.factorydirectfilters.com/actual-vs-nominal-size your filter is 25 x 16 x 4"

From the same web site:
http://www.factorydirectfilters.com/air-filters/4inch/16x25x4.html
the numbers match the ones you've provided in your post.

I can't assess the pricing aspect, however. They sure are expensive, regardless of size, aren't they?

Comment: The website is the site for the furnace installer. They don't indicate who their air filter supplier is.

Comment: That's an unfortunate misdirection. I've ordered from filtersfast.com as they were the lowest price I found at the time.  https://www.filtersfast.com/listbysize2.asp?size=16x25x4

Answer (score 1):

If you want a direct replacement, you're looking for a 16x25x4 MERV 8 filter.

16x25x4 is the nominal size, the actual dimensions of the filter should be 15 1/2" x 24 1/2" x 3 9/16".